# Casting a char valued 255 leads to an unsigned int value of 4294967295, what gives?

Tags: c++, casting

OK, this is a strange issue that I've been having that I've never seen before:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  char testchar = 255;
  std::cout << (unsigned int)testchar << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
4294967295
```

What in the heck? It seems that because the char is "full," when it generates the new unsigned int type the result is "full" as well. This is not the result I remember or that I expect. I would expect the unsigned int to have a value of 0x000000FF. Can anybody explain to me exactly what's going on here?

System: Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit

g++ version: 4.6.3

Comment: Fiddled the question title to be extra-specific in an attempt to help people who search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `char` is apparently signed. That means the `255` is overflowing the `char`. Since you're apparently on a 2's complement machine, the bit-pattern of the 255 is being stored in the `char` (i.e., all bits are set). When interpreted as a signed 8-bit number, that's -1.

Then *that* value is sign-extended out to a 32-bit `int`, giving 32 1 bits (but the same value, `-1`). Finally, that value is converted to `unsigned int`. According to the rules that's done by reduction modulo 2<sup>32</sup>-1, which gives the largest possible 32-bit number (4294967295).

Comment: `When a signed integer is converted to an unsigned integer with
equal or greater size, if the value of the signed integer is
nonnegative, its value is unchanged.  Otherwise: if the unsigned
integer has greater size, the signed integer is first promoted to the
signed integer corresponding to the unsigned integer; the value is
converted to unsigned by adding to it one greater than the largest
number that can be represented in the unsigned integer type.` quoted from http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt

Comment: It's been a long while since I've coded in C. I never considered that a char would be signed by default - doesn't really make much sense to me. Now I'm having issues defining pointers to unsigned chars *sigh* Well, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Githlar: Maybe you just want to cast to `unsigned char` first, and then to `unsigend int`.